# I am trying to get image link(.jpg) using requests_html. can anyone help me?

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests-html

1. I tried requests_html
2. For links, I tried links and absolute links.

---

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session=HTMLSession()

url='https://www.shutterstock.com/featured-collections/autumn-208192415'

r=session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=1,keep_page=True, scrolldown=1)

images=r.html.find('img')


for item in images:

    links={
            'link':item.links
           }

    print(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all images, you can extract the link from `<a>` tag. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.shutterstock.com/featured-collections/autumn-208192415'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a:has(> img)'):
    href, num = ('https://image.shutterstock.com' + a['href']).rsplit('-', maxsplit=1)
    print(href + '-260nw-' + num + '.jpg')
```

Prints:

```
...

https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/autumn-nature-hiker-girl-walking-national-260nw-718962793.jpg
https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/autumn-composition-wreath-made-leaves-pine-260nw-700154173.jpg
https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/autumn-mountain-forest-lake-house-reflection-260nw-1068990077.jpg
https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/popular-photographers-attraction-braies-lake-colorful-260nw-705417145.jpg
https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/floral-autumn-background-mug-coffee-womans-260nw-717249397.jpg
https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/autumn-forest-nature-vivid-morning-colorful-260nw-766886038.jpg
https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/autumn-season-hipster-style-shoes-260nw-310459334.jpg
https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/autumn-forest-lake-reflection-landscape-260nw-1128352901.jpg
```